# Why use .env file when you can set it up in a .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, development-environment, environment, production-environment

Im curios why we need to bother making a .env file, when you can do the same with exporting a .js file. Isn't the main purpose of a .env file is for differentiation between production and development? Thank you.

Comment: It is to have all environment variables externalized from the main code (that uses it) - this allows you to build quickly for different target environments (using automated methods: build pipelines, etc) without changing your code

Comment: the file itself might be imported by your code but also by the build systems

Comment: It's a nice default format, that works across languages and can be ignored in non-dev environments where you have better means to specify environment variables.

Comment: does that mean everytime we change our environment we need to make a new .env file?

Comment: you define .env file for different environment, normally dev, test, preview and production.if it's more than that, it is possible you've put abnormal env variable in .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing configurations as environment variables allow us to

- Easily change the system behaviour in different environments without changing the source code.
- A way to keep secrets like API keys out of the code.

https://12factor.net/config