# Is there any special meaning in storing variables into a .env file?

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables

There are people who recommend to use a `.env` file to store certain values for settings, I use a Dart static class for my constants or setting values, so why to use a `.env` file? more secure? why? If my Flutter app is intended for Android/IOS/Windows, makes sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use .env file when you can set it up in a .js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227582/why-use-env-file-when-you-can-set-it-up-in-a-js-file)

Comment: Nop, their target platforms are different, and the reasons exposed by the accepted answer is done by my Dart static class which is used by different parts of my code as variables. So I return my original question.

Answer (score 2):

From what you're mentioning I understand that you're trying to understand the difference between having values inside a dot env file compared with having those values bundle within your Dart/Flutter project

If that's the case, there is a huge difference between dot env files and hardcoding values inside your codebase.

1. `.env` file

Usually when people use dot env files, the values inside these files are passed to your Flutter application as parameters and the Flutter app reads these parameters during runtime. This means that you can hot-swap these dot env files depending on your choices and environments, etc.

2. Hardcoding in the app

When you hardcode values inside your app, they get compiled and shipped with your application meaning that they are more exposed to others.

So depending on the values you want to pass to your app, you can make a decision on whether you want to put those values in dot env files or hardcoded in your app.

Comment: I can understand the desire to swap them out for development purposes, but I don't understand the claim that hardcoding them in the app is somehow less secure. Consider a native Flutter app distributed through an App Store. Where do these values from `.env` live? They must be baked into the binary that gets distributed somehow, in order to be used. Can you help clarify this point?